Can psychological disorders be mitigated through philosophy?
Psychological disorders are often (for obvious reasons) considered part of psychology. Many of the treatments involve either medication or some sort of behavioral therapy.
A special form of behavioral therapy called cognitive behavioral therapy is summarized as follows:

Cognitive behavioral therapy focuses on challenging and changing cognitive distortions (such as thoughts, beliefs, and attitudes) and their associated behaviors to improve emotional regulation and develop personal coping strategies that target solving current problems.

Are there then techniques in philosophy that can help change “cognitive distortions”? If beliefs are part of philosophy, and cognitive distortions presumably refer to false beliefs, could philosophy then be used to help demarcate between true and false beliefs and thus alleviate psychological disorders?

I’m voting to close this question because it belongs to https://psychology.stackexchange.com/

Anything can be used in CBT, including philosophy, but this is too obvious to make it a good answer. It's unclear what the question wants to know beyond this obvious triviality.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philosophical_counseling Also Buddhist philosophy is aimed at helping people improve their mental state, similar to Stoic philosophy.

If one has spent much time or know philosophy well, one can certainly apply philosophy at least as a complementary tool for CBT, especially from areas like epistemology, ethics and existential philosophy. For example if psychological disorders result from certain updated cognitive belief based on some experienced evidential data in a Bayesian fashion, just because the updated belief aligns with the data and seems reasonable doesn't necessarily mean it's a justified or authentic truth-tracking knowledge. One may apply the famous Gettier problem to help to rectify one's confounding disorder...

@DoubleKnot I wonder also if a psychological disorder could also manifest from a degree of belief simply not matching to an emotion correctly. For example, one may inconsistently have a low degree of belief in a negative outcome but a high degree of fear of distress with respect to that same outcome

I’m voting to close this question because it is best to follow the advice of a psychologist or psychotherapist. Philosophical laymen like most of us are not experts and can only make opinion-based proposals. I would ask this question to a psychological professional who is familiar with the specific case.

That depends on what one considers philosophy to be. There are various schools of thought in philosophy. In general, Schopenhauer identified what constitutes a delusional disorder. People assume that something happens in the world without a direct causal reason for it. For Schopenhauer, this was the horror of delusion. Nietzsche further noted that Schopenhauer overlooked the fact that such a delusion could also evoke a sense of rapture. Through logical and rigorous thinking, this might be alleviated within the subclinical realm, as one becomes reacquainted with an immanent worldview. However, Hegel would only exacerbate the problem and could even contribute to such disorders himself.
